# Even natural numbers are sums of two primes with twins or of two primes without twins

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, computational-mathematics, conjectures, goldbachs-conjecture

I seems to be very few even numbers that can't be written as a sum of two primes with twins *or* as a sum of two primes without twins.

That is, suppose that $\mathbb P'$ is the set of the primes not belonging to a  twin and that $\mathbb P''$ is the set of the primes belonging to a twin, then all but a finite number of even natural numbers can be written as $2n=p'+q',\quad p',q'\in\mathbb P'$ or
as $2n=p''+q'',\quad p'',q''\in\mathbb P''$, due to a conjecture.

So far the only exceptions are $0,2,96,98$ of even numbers $<100,000,000$.

I'm interested in counterexamples and references.

Below the number of ways to write $1000$ as sum of two twin primes is 3, and the number of ways to write $1000$ as sum of two non twin primes is $10$.

```
100 terms cardinality . cardinality . 1 2  ok
1000 terms cardinality . cardinality . 10 3  ok
10000 terms cardinality . cardinality . 63 10  ok
100000 terms cardinality . cardinality . 415 64  ok
1000000 terms cardinality . cardinality . 3455 167  ok
10000000 terms cardinality . cardinality . 27081 1259  ok
100000000 terms cardinality . cardinality . 210124 5854  ok
```

I see now that it seems to be a conjecture for the case 
$2n=p'+q',\quad p',q'\in\mathbb P'$, but then with a larger number of small exceptions:
{0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58,62,64,66,68,72,78,80,82,86,88,92,96,98,108,110,118,122,124,128,138,140,148,152,170,182,188,208,212,218,222,232,238,266,268,272,282,292,296,328,332,358,362,392,482,512,628}.

The corresponding set of small exceptions in the case 
$2n=p''+q'',\quad p'',q''\in\mathbb P''$ is:
{0,2,94,96,98,400,402,404,514,516,518,784,786,788,904,906,908,1114,1116,1118,1144,1146,1148,1264,1266,1268,1354,1356,1358,3244,3246,3248,4204,4206,4208}.

And the intersection is {0,2,96,98}.

Comment: what do you get under the probabilistic model : mark $2k+1$ as prime with a probability $\frac{2}{\ln (2k+1)}$ ?

Comment: @user1952009: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Lehs you never saw the probabilistic model for the distribution of prime numbers ?

Comment: @user1952009 this does not help much here because we have to distinguish between primes belonging to a twin and primes not belonging to a twin.

Comment: We probably have only finite many exceptions because most of the large primes do not belong to a twin.

Comment: @Peter it does help, it should say the number of ways of writing $2n$ as $p+q$ grows faster than the number of twin primes, so the probability that there are only finitely many counter-examples is $1$ (it is only heuristic, but it fits the reality perfectly well for almost every problem related to the prime numbers)

Comment: If memory serves correctly, someone has already replied in a comment to one of your previous questions of similar nature, stating that it is very easy to come up with this type of conjectures, but very hard to prove them (as is the case with Goldbach's conjecture).